# Anyone can explain to me document.cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I found this code in w3schoool JavaScript cookie section, which is to read the cookie:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
  if (document.cookie.length>0)
  {
    c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start!=-1)
    {
      c_start = c_start + c_name.length+1;
      c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
      if (c_end==-1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

In this line:

```
if (document.cookie.length > 0)
```

what `document.cookie.length` means?

In this line:

```
c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
```

why I need to add `=` after the `c_name(cookie name)`?

In this line:

```
c_start = c_start + c_name.length+1;
```

why I need to add `c_name.length+1`? What the purpose?

And what the meaning of this line:

```
  if (c_end==-1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
```

Can Anyone answer my question? Thanks!!!

Comment: At least one of these questions was already answered in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703128/what-mean-length-in-document-cookie). And anyway, why don't you examine the code yourself a bit? You can insert `alert` or `console.log` and see what the content of the variables is and what the differences is between using `+1` or not....

Comment: [W3Schools is a bad reference.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Wish there was a wiki with all references of all libraries and all languages. Not thousands of HTML references, thousands of C references, and so on. :)

Comment: If you want a *good* cookie script, with *full* explanation, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: See also [Javascript getCookie functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

document.cookie is a string, with key=value pairs separated by semicolons (;).

the code you pasted looks for a specific key in the string, and then finding its value by looking for the end of the string, or the next semicolon, and returning the value it found

so for example, if document.cookie === "someKey=aCookieMadeMeHaveValue7;anotherKey=aShorterValue", you can search for the value of someKey by executing the function getCookie('someKey'), which will look at the string, and return 'aCookieMadeMeHaveValue7'.

it will add +1 to that position so as to jump over the '=', and then return the string from there until the first time it sees a ';' or comes to the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

`document.cookie` returns a string containing the cookies. Everything else you ask about is pretty standard javascript string manipulation.

```
if (document.cookie.length > 0)
```

checks if the string is not empty.

```
c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
```

finds the index of the first occurrence of the `COOKIENAME=` substring in the string.

```
c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
```

positions the index after the cookie name in the string

```
c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
```

tries to find the first occurrence of the `;` character starting from the `c_start` position and if this character is not found it positions to the end of the string.

Comment: revise you answer about `c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");` please ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, quick answers. Firstly, `document.cookie` is a string containing `key=value` pairs for each cookie set on this domain.

(1) `if (document.cookie.length>0)` checks that there are some cookies set, i.e. that the string is not empty.

(2) `c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");` the `=` is needed to make sure that `c_name` does not occur inside the value of a cookie, only in the key.

(3) `c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;` `c_start` is the place where the key has been found in the string. You then need to add the length of the key plus one (for the `=`) to find the start of the value.

(4) `if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;` If the cookie is the last one, there will be no terminating `;`, so we look for the very end of the string instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) is a string and the `length` property holds the length of the string in characters.

The `=` is appended to the cookie name because the cookie name could also appear somewhere else in the `document.cookie` string (like in the cookie value of another cookie). The `c_name.length+1` is used because the `+1` reflects the `=` after the cookie name. And `indexOf` return `-1` if the needle could not be found in the haystack; that’s why `c_end` is compared to `-1`.

But you shouldn’t use this implementation. Take a look at [my answer to *Javascript getCookie functions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions/4004010#4004010) to see why it’s wrong and how a better implementation could look like.